# best practice to avoid GWT's com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException early

Tags: gwt, serialization, gwt-rpc

What recommendable ways are there to enforce/check serializability of an entire GWT module? For example, can we tell the gwt compiler in a gwt module descriptor file or using the configuration section of the gwt maven plugin to throw errors if some types are not serializable?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion an APT(Annotation Processor Tool) could be made for validating entities transported between the server and the client.The APT would be something similar to that used to validate the Request Factory proxies at compile time.

I am not familiar with APT, but I think you could check the entity serializability at compile time with APT.

Check this links out:

http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17876.html 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/apt/index.html
Hope this was helpful.